# how to center a div which has a width dependent on content

Tags: html, css, center

I have a div which would be filled dynamically with images ect, and which would have a width that depends on the number of images.  How can I center such a div?

```
<div class="info_div">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="item_list">
             <h2>Item Title  vbakjlkak;;kkl;lk;k</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info_div {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
background-size: cover;
z-index: 3000;
overflow: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0%;
}

.item_list {
max-width:50%;
min-width:150px;
background: #ffeec0;
padding:2px;
margin:3px;
border-radius: 2px;
border:1px solid #ffdd7c;
float:  left;
clear: left;
display: inline-block;
}

 .center {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:600px;
 }
```

Comment: Which div is it that you wish to center? item_list?

Comment: that's the one.   but keeping its width dependent on content :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `display:inline-block;` to the `.center` and then give `text-align:center` to its parent.

```css
.info_div {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
background-size: cover;
z-index: 3000;
overflow: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0%;
  text-align:center;
}

.item_list {
max-width:50%;
min-width:150px;
background: #ffeec0;
padding:2px;
margin:3px;
border-radius: 2px;
border:1px solid #ffdd7c;
float:  left;
clear: left;
display: inline-block;
}

 .center {
 display:inline-block;
   background-color: red;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="info_div">
<div class="center">
    <div class="item_list">
        <h2>Item Title  vbakjlkak;;kkl;lk;k</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is `item_list` that you want centering, you can use this CSS:

```
.item_list {
max-width:50%;
min-width:150px;
background: #ffeec0;
padding:2px;
margin:3px;
border-radius: 2px;
border:1px solid #ffdd7c;
clear: left;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

i.e. remove the `float:left;`, the `display:inline-block`, and add `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
 .center {
            background-color: #F00;
margin: 0px auto;
align-self: center;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
display: inline-flex;
width: 600px;
        }
        .item_list {
         background: #FFEEC0 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0px auto !important;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid #FFDD7C;
word-break: break-all;
overflow: visible;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
        }
```